# Microphone not working in Zoom and Skype

Tags: sound, 20.04, skype, microphone

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and have been using both Skype and Zoom Desktop app on it.
But couple of weeks ago (probably after some system upgrade) my mic stopped working in both apps.
The device itself is working ok - I checked with "sound recording". It also works in Google Meet and other WebRTC based video conference systems.

In Skype I can connect but nobody can hear me. When doing test call I can only hear beaping sound but after that there is no "Welcome to test Skype" message.

In Zoom also nobody can hear me. I tried testing Audio in Settings but the Input Level bar is not showing any changes when I speak.
I also tried other devides - usb based headphones - with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem with Zoom. It turnes out that mic was muted for Zoom appication. But this setting was only visible when Zoom was running and after clicking randomly on Zoom's microphone selection dropdown...

Answer (score 2):

Tried the suggestions here but still didn't work. Instead, this works for me:

- log in and set up everything on Zoom browser, then
- join or host a meeting from there

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xorg or Wayland? You can select this when you login: "Ubuntu" vs "Ubuntu on Wayland".

In my case, specifically Skype and Zoom seem to have the same issue on Wayland at the moment, switching to Xorg (the default) works.